# LicenseTracker - Unable to wait for LicenseTracker to stop

Tags: web8, microservices

On several Web 8.1 micro services I get this error in the logs

```
 2017-03-31 00:04:17,207 ERROR LicenseTracker - Unable to wait for LicenseTracker to stop
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6):

It means the SDL Web licenses are expired. Check the `cd_licenses.xml` which contains those licenses.

Comment: That was obvious from the error message, wasn't it? ;-)